# Sharing variable across multiple files

Tags: node.js, express

Would like to know a "good" way of sharing a variable for the following scenario.

My `server.js` file includes an `authenticator.js` file like so:

```
var authenticator = require('./server/services/authenticator')(app);
app.use(authenticator);
```

Within the `authenticator.js` file there is a variable called privateKey:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  var authenticator = function (req, res, next) {
    //do some stuff here

    var privateKey = 'value from Basic Auth header'

  };
  return authenticator;
};
```

My `api.js` file now needs this `privateKey` variable.

I include the `api.js` file from my `server.js` in the same way:

```
var api = require('./server/api')(app);
app.use('/v1', api);
```

and I would like to pass the `privateKey` too using something like:

```
var api = require('./server/api')(app, privateKey);
```

**QUESTION:** How can I make `privateKey` available in my `server.js` file so that I can pass it to the `api.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach it to the req variable

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var authenticator = function(req, res, next) {
        //do some stuff here
        req.privateKey = 'value from Basic Auth header'; //This can be shared accross middlewares.
        next(); //don't forget to call this.
    };
    return authenticator;
};
```

server.js

---

```
var api = require('./server/api')(app);
app.use('/v1', api);
```

api.js

---

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    var api = function(req, res, next) {
        var privateKey = req.privateKey; //this is how we can use it
        //do something with it
        next();
    };
    return api;
};
```

}

Comment: This is the way I've decided to do it actually.

Comment: This definitely works. My general thrust though is that if it is something that will be set with each request, then I will set it on `req`, else I will make it part of exports.